# What is the equivalent of ASP(VB) Server.CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog") in ASP.net (VB.net)

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic

Hi
I am trying to convert a asp page to asp.net.
I changed everything except this one line
 `Set dbC = Server.CreateObject("ADOX.Catalog")`

Can anyone suggest an equivalent to this ADOX.Catalog in asp.net

This dbC is being used in the following way in asp

```
Set cm = Server.CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
cm.CommandText = Request("qry")

sN = Request("sN")
Set tmpTable = dbC.Tables(sN)
if NOT IsObject(tmpTable) then
  dbC.Views.Append sN, cm
else
  tmpTble.Command = cm
end if
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I do not have direct experience, this article seems like it would be of assistance to you:

[How To Retrieve Schema Information by Using GetOleDbSchemaTable and Visual C# .NET](http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;Q309681)

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a reference into your project called, **Microsoft ADO ext.6.0 for DLL and security** or something similar.

Once you add it, you'd be able to write code like:

```
Dim dbc as New ADOX.Catalog
```

Ps: Not answering from a windows m/c to verify. Got this from another forum [post](http://bytes.com/topic/net/answers/642938-how-import-adox)